# Error : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, database

## ERROR MESSAGE in SERVER

```
    [2019-01-07 09:44:02] ERROR 
    :com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications 
    link failure
    [2019-01-07 09:44:02]
    [2019-01-07 09:44:02] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 
    milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

## But testing in local.. No problem.. No Error message..

1. Commit libraries..

   ```
   mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar 
   mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar
   ```
2. JDBC URL ALTER

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/ID -> jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/ID?autoReconnect=true
   ```

   Changed Error Message..

   ```
   [2019-01-07 11:04:32] Error : 
   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could 
   not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. 
   Giving up.
   ```

## ControlDAO.java

```
private final static String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private final static String URL = 
"jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/ID?autoReconnect=true;

public static void CsNumberCheck(String s) { 
    try {           
        Class.forName(DRIVER);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "ID", "PW");
        System.out.println(conn);

        stat = conn.createStatement();

        int result = 0;

        sql = Query;

        rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);

        while ( rs.next() ) {
            result = rs.getInt(1);
        }

        rs.close();
        stat.close();

        System.out.println(result);

        CsNumberResult(result, OrangeEmail);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver Loading Failed..");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + e);
    }
}
```

## Socket.java

```
     ControlDAO.CsNumberCheck(s);
```

- But nothing result about "Sysout", Only Error Message....

Comment: In your exception handling place, do a `e.printStackTrace();` and then edit your question with your stacktrace

Comment: Okay, I answered..

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: 연결 시간 초과 (Connection timed out)
[2019-01-07 12:15:46]   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  - can you connect using some other client tool?

Comment: Umm For example??

Comment: MySql workbench or Eclipse

Comment: I used Eclipse SVN. So testing in local isn't error.. But if programs execute, errors will arise after commit code on server

Answer (score 0):

Check your windows services to see if your MySQL server is running. That might be a probable cause. If it's not, start it and try to reconnect.